# Change the discount in the Order Details table on all orders of products of an ordered quantity

Tags: sql, sql-server

how do I write a script to change the discount in the Order Details table on all orders of products of an ordered quantity of more than 50 to that of the largest discount ever given on any product.In the northwinds table?
I just need direction, do I use subqueries and how do I get the largest discount?

Answer (score 2):

You're best off using temp tables.

First, select into a temp table the products and their largest discounts.

Next, select into a temp table a list of product instances (I assume there's a key value) with ordered quantities greater than 50.

Lastly, do an update on your Order Details table joined to the two temp tables.  Inner joins in both cases.

If you want to make it a single query, you can make those two temp tables into subqueries, but using temp tables is way more efficient.  More code, but easier to parse and runs faster.